# List<T>Contains Method as Extension method not working?

Tags: c#

I want to write an extension method Like the Contains method of the List class for the List class that takes an `null` able object. 
My Extension method is :

```
public static class CustomList
    {
        public static bool Contains<T>(this List<T> lst, Nullable<T> obj) where T : struct
        {
            bool bContains = false;
            if (obj == null)
            {
                bContains = false;
            }
            else
            {
                T obj1 = (T)obj.Value;
                bContains = lst.Contains(obj1);
            }

            return bContains;
        }
}
```

My  LINQ code which calls the extension method is given below:

```
var lstJobActivity = (from objActivity in context.VW_JOB_ACTIVITY
                                  where JobAssignId.Contains(objActivity.ASSIGN_ID) && objActivity.ACTIVITY_TYPE == "JBINTV"
                                  select objActivity).ToList<VW_JOB_ACTIVITY>();
```

where `objActivity.ASSIGN_ID` is `null`.

The error is showing is given below:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int64](System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64], System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Check this link, it might help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean-containsdecimal

Comment: could you not use `JobAssignId.Where(x => x.ASSIGN_ID.Equals(objActivity.ASSIGN_ID).Any()` that would be better

Comment: As I said in your other question, you're asking the wrong thing here. You don't want to write an extension method as it won't translate to LINQ to Entities. You want to figure out how to make LINQ to Enitities do this using the standard methods.

Comment: @MatthewWatson My answer is relevant to both questions, if you're asking.

Comment: @Rawling I see it now. I was expecting a green tick. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that that LINQ has to build a query and pass it on to the database engine.  You're specifying this function as part of the query, and LINQ is smart enough to know that the database engine hasn't a clue how to execute this function.