# How to use feature like Contains in LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have this query :

```
int[] listId = {15, 56, 89, 24}
var queryError = from error in db.errors
                 where listId.Contains(error.battery_id)                                    
                 select error;

 List<error> bufferErrorList = new List<error>();
 bufferErrorList = queryError.ToList();
```

But i get the error message :

> LINQ to Entities dont recognise the method « Boolean
>   Contains(System.Object) », so it cannot be translated.

How can I get my results ?

Thanks !

Comment: What type is `error.battery_id`?

Comment: But compiler says it's `object`. Check your model.

Comment: its a very common issue and already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean-containsdecimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried casting the object as an int?

```
where listId.Contains((int)error.battery_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean-containsdecimal)

Try something like this:

```
int[] listId = {15, 56, 89, 24}
var queryError = from error in db.errors
                 where listId.Any(x => x == error.battery_id)                                    
                 select error;

 List<error> bufferErrorList = new List<error>();
 bufferErrorList = queryError.ToList();
```

Comment: You could shorten the above to listId.Any(x => x == error.battery_id)

Comment: I only know this because someone pointed it out to me in the past. :)

Comment: and you just did it to me too

Comment: That's the power of stackoverflow :)